# ion-menu is not doing animation, how to add animation

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I saw it in the ionic documentation but I couldn't find anything about it.
When I click on the button to open the menu it is opening normally but without any animation, how do I add an animation for when the menu opens and closes???

```html
      <div class="toatal_pages">
        <ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="main" >
          <ion-content>
            info
            </ion-content>
        </ion-menu>
        <div class="right> id="main">
        <button (click)="openMenu()"> OPEN MENU</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
        async openMenu() {
          await this.menuController.open();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure you are importing it from angular
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

```
#Try this.

 // template code :
<ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="main">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>
<ion-content>
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
  <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
  <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
  <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
  <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

```
//TypeScript code 
constructor(private menu: MenuController) { }

openMenu() {
    this.menu.enable(true, 'first');
    this.menu.open('first');
}
```

Comment: There is not any built in animation method in it. Its default animation is implemented automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the default animations then ensure that you have the CSS provided from ionic are imported in the app

For custom animations you will need to follow the following [Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/animations#overview) from Ionic

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular issue...
Check your app module and be sure that animated is not set to false at your Ionic Module import:

```
imports: [
...
IonicModule.forRoot(animated: true),
...
]
```